# Failed to instantiate UriInfo Specified class is an interface

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I want to use annotation @Context to retrieve the URI

```
@GetMapping(value = "/profile/{username}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Response getProfile(
        @PathVariable String username,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo
) {
    return Optional
            .ofNullable(userService.findOneByUsername(username))
            .map(user -> Response
                          .created(uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(username).build())
                          .status(Response.Status.OK)
                          .entity(user).build())
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                throw new ProfileNotFoundException();
            });
}
```

However, while displaying the page throws an exception

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo]: Specified class is an interface
```

I can not find information on how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

`UriInfo` isn't a part Spring MVC. You can use  [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) in Spring MVC for this